# VSTS Build Fails in the Nuget Restore step

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I am building .net code using hosted agent in VSTS but the build is failing,below is the error where exactly i need to change or add something.Its failing in the nuget restore step when i am trying to restore packages from the solution
[image]

Comment: can you check the previous output of the task for errors/warnings and include them in the question ? nuget will surely have logged something before but without that logging it is hard to tell what's going wrong here

Comment: Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and post the detail log here.

Comment: i have set system.debug to true

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? What're detail steps to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

We were having the same issue - we believe the Azure team released a new version over the past few days that caused our NuGet Restore tasks to start failing.

We were using a custom nuget.config file with our own packageSource.  Our custom packageSource key had spaces and parenthesis.  Once we removed these characters, the builds started to succeed again.

The issue likely stemmed from the custom packageSources being converted to XML element names. The characters I mentioned are invalid in XML element names which was causing our problem.